# Apex - Count days or years between today and Date field (Registration date)

Tags: apex, trigger, date

I need to make discount depends from Registration date (i.e. 3% discount to Opportunity when Accoun registered 1-2 years ago). Sample of code:

```
 for (Opportunity opp : TriggeredOpps){
        If (Account.Registration_Date__c != null){
            Date todayDate = Date.today();
            Date RegDay = opp.Account.Registration_Date__c;
            Integer numberOfDays = RegDay.daysBetween(todayDate);
            if(numberOfDays >= 365 || numberOfDays < 730 ){
                for (Discount__mdt disc : DiscountRecords){
                    if(disc.Years_Sinse_Reg__c == 1){
                        opp.Amount = opp.Amount - (opp.Amount*(disc.Discount__c / 100));
                    }
                }
            }
        }   
    }
```

but part `Integer numberOfDays = RegDay.daysBetween(todayDate)` doesn't work.
Can somebody help with what is wrong here?

During manual testing

> System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object
> Class.OpportunityTriggerHandler.DiscountOpportunityRegDay: line 48,
> column 1

line 48 - it's exactly `Integer numberOfDays = RegDay.daysBetween(todayDate)`

Comment: what exactly problem are you facing ? some exceptions during code execution?

Comment: During manual testing "System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object Class.OpportunityTriggerHandler.DiscountOpportunityRegDay: line 48, column 1" - line 48 - it's exactly Integer numberOfDays = RegDay.daysBetween(todayDate)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can make an assumption, that you are calling this code from the `Opportunity` trigger. That means opportunity fields of the trigger context records will be accessible e.g.

```
for (Opportunity opp : TriggeredOpps){
    System.debug(opp.Amount); // will be accessible
....
```

However, if you want to access parent fields, you need explicitly to query them. In this example, in the trigger context field, `opp.Account.Registration_Date__c` is not populated. You need to query it. That is why you do have `NullPointerException`.

Also, you have a wrong checking for null in `if` condition.

```
if (Account.Registration_Date__c != null){
```

this checks, if sobjectfield is not `null`. (and of cause it is not `null`)

that should be:

```
if (opp.Account.Registration_Date__c != null){
```

---

In general you code should be like:

```
// collect parent `AccountId`s
Set<Id> accountIdsSet = new Set<Id>();
for (Opportunity opp : TriggeredOpps){
    accountIdsSet.add(opp.AccountId);
}
accountIdsSet.remove(null);

//explicitly querieng parent accounts to get account field values
Map<Id, Account> parentAccountsMap = new Map<Id, Account>([
    SELECT Id, Registration_Date__c
    FROM Account
    WHERE Id IN :accountIdsSet
]);

for (Opportunity opp : TriggeredOpps){
    Account parentAccount = parentAccountsMap.get(opp.AccountId);
    If (parentAccount.Registration_Date__c != null){
        Date todayDate = Date.today();
        Date RegDay = parentAccount.Registration_Date__c;
        Integer numberOfDays = RegDay.daysBetween(todayDate);
        if(numberOfDays >= 365 || numberOfDays < 730 ){
            for (Discount__mdt disc : DiscountRecords){
                if(disc.Years_Sinse_Reg__c == 1){
                    opp.Amount = opp.Amount - (opp.Amount*(disc.Discount__c / 100));
                }
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: Great! I'm a newbie and your detailed answer helped me a lot! Thanks Oleksandr!

Comment: @IvanSholok We all were newbies one day. Happy to help

Answer (score 0):

If `RegDay` was in the past, then

```
Integer numberOfDays = RegDay.daysBetween(todayDate);
```

will result in a negative number.

You would probably want to try:

```
Integer numberOfDays = todaysDate.daysBetween(RegDay);
```